# Alternative methods to prove that $Z_m$ is a field under addition and multiplication $\bmod\ m$ iff $m$ is a prime

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, number-theory

> I am looking for ways to prove that $\mathbb{Z}_m=\{0,1,2,\dots,m-1\}$ is a field under addition and multiplication $\bmod\ m$ iff $m$ is a prime.

I tried it this way:
If $m$ is a prime $p$,it is obvious that most importantly, we need to prove that every non-zero element in $\mathbb{Z_p}$ has an inverse in $\mathbb{Z_p}$.We note that if $a,b\in \mathbb{Z_p}$, then $a\cdot b\in \mathbb{Z_p} \dots \boxed{*}$. Next, $a^p\equiv a \bmod p$ for prime $p$(the proof follows by induction on $a$).As  $\displaystyle 0\leq a\leq p-1$,$a\not =p$. Thus $$a^{p-1}\equiv 1 \bmod p$$ for prime $p$ which,together with $\boxed{*}$ guarantees the existence of an inverse in $\mathbb{Z_p}$.Proving the other properties is simple.

Conversely,if $\mathbb{Z_m}$ is a field,then every non-zero element of $\mathbb{Z_m}$ has an inverse.Note that inverse of an element is unique.For if $a\cdot b\equiv a\cdot c\equiv 1 \bmod m$,then $(a\cdot b)\cdot c\equiv c\equiv (a\cdot c)\cdot b\equiv b \bmod m$ i.e $m|(b-c)\implies b-c=0(0\leq a\leq m-1,a\in \mathbb{Z_m})$.So, inverses must be unique and every element is either an inverse of itself or has in inverse in the field.That allows us to conclude that $[(m-1)!]^2\equiv 1 \bmod m$ which can only mean that either 
$(m-1)!\equiv 1 \bmod m$ or $(m-1)!\equiv -1 \bmod m$. If $m$ is not a prime, it has a prime factor, say $p$. $ 0\leq p\leq m-1\implies p|(m-1)!\implies p|1$or $-1$ which is absurd, a contradiction.Thus $m$ is prime.

I feel that this method is too involved and complicated. Can anyone please suggest some other method?(Some context: This is a problem from *Finite Dimensional Vector Spaces* by Paul Halmos. I am learning linear algebra for the first time.It seems some of the comments have been posted on the assumption that I know rings and fields; I don't. )

Comment: Fields do not have zero divisors, but $d(\frac{m}{d}) \equiv 0\pmod{m}$ if $d|m$.

Comment: apart from proving every element is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.. how do you see that it is integral domain first of all? btw, you are making your life so complicated by using too many ideas for simple questions...

Comment: You could use the result that for a ring $R$ and an ideal $M$ the quotient $R/M$ is a field iff $M$ is maximal. $\Bbb Z$ is a ring, so $\Bbb Z_p\approx\Bbb Z/\langle p\rangle$ is a field iff $\langle p\rangle$ is maximal iff $p$ is prime (since $\Bbb Z$ is a Principal Ideal Domain). This requires some background in algebra, though.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik,is there any reason for you to suppose that I know rings and fields in details?

Comment: i did not suppose you know rings and fields in detail... I believe that Only if you do not know in detail you will ask for somebody's help.... So....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{Z}_m$ is a ring, it follows that $\mathbb{Z}_m$ is a field if and only if every nonzero element of $\mathbb{Z}_m$ is invertible.

I think the following proof is straightforward, and it is the most common one I have seen in algebra/number theory textbooks.

If $m$ is not prime, then $m = ab$, where $1 < a < m$ and $1 < b < m$. I claim that $a$ does not have an inverse in $\mathbb{Z}_m$. If $ax = 1 \mod{m}$, then $abx = b \mod{m}$. But $ab = 0$ modulo $m$, which implies $b = 0 \mod{m}$, a contradiction.

Suppose that $m$ is a prime, and let $1 \leq a < m$. Now $\gcd(a,m) = 1$, so by Bezout's theorem $ax + my = 1$ for some integers $x$ and $y$. Hence $ax = 1 \mod{m}$ and $a$ is invertible modulo $m$.

Comment: This is wonderful,again.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $a\in \mathbb{Z}_m$ with $a\ne0$ and the map $\mu: x \mapsto ax$.

Then $\mathbb{Z}_m$ is a field iff $\mu$ is surjective. Since $\mathbb{Z}_m$ is finite, this is equivalent to $\mu$ is injective.

Now  $\mu$ is injective iff ($\mu(x)=0$ implies $x=0$) iff ($m \mid ax$ implies $m \mid a$ or $m \mid x$).

This proves that $\mu$ is injective when $m$ prime.

If $m$ is not prime, then writing $m=ab$ with $1<a,b<m$ gives $\mu(b)=0$ and $\mu$ is not injective for that $a$.

Comment: Note the parallel with the important linear algebra theorem that, for a square matrix $A$, the system $Ax=b$ has a solution for every $b$ iff $Ax=0$ has only the trivial solution $x=0$. (In other words, $x\mapsto Ax$ is surjective iff it is injective

Comment: This is really good. I couldn't have come up with this myself.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative proof, which might be a motivation to learn ring theory later: Let $\varphi:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/p$ be the quotient map. If $\mathbb{Z}/p$ is not a field, it contains a *nonzero* maximal ideal $M\subset \mathbb{Z}/p$. Since $\varphi$ is surjective, we get an inclusion $(p)\subset \varphi^{-1}(M)$ of *distinct* prime ideals in $\mathbb{Z}$. However, $\mathbb{Z}$ is Euclidean, hence a principal ideal domain so every nonzero prime is in fact maximal, which is a contradiction to the inclusion of distinct prime ideals we found.