# Show $(\mathbb{Z}/n, +, \cdot)$ is a field iff $n$ prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I was requested to show $(\mathbb{Z}/n, +, \cdot)$ is a field iff $n$ prime. I'm only working on the $\Rightarrow$ implication. I am very new to algebra and was wondering what I needed to prove exactly.

Since $\mathbb{Z}/n \subset \mathbb{N}$ and $+, \cdot$ are conmutative and associative in $\mathbb{N}$, it seems one must only show they have inverses and neutral elements in $\mathbb{Z}/n$ if $n$ is prime, and that they are closed. I will show some of the demonstrations so you might get a grasp of my understanding of the subject, and then I'll ask the specific question I have.

$\text{Assumption : }$Assume $n$ is prime. Then $\mathbb{Z}/n =\{1, 2, ..., n-1\}$.

$\text{Closedness :}$  Let $a, b \in  \mathbb{Z}/n$. Then $a+b<n$ or $a+b \geq n$. If $a +b<n$ then $a+b \in \mathbb{Z}/n$. If $a+b \geq n$ then $a+b= n+k$ with $0<k<n$, which means $a+b \equiv k \pmod{n}$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}/n$ (due to our assumption). Then $\mathbb{Z}/n$ is closed under $+$.

$\text{Neutral elements : }$ We know $1$ is the neutral element of $\cdot$ and we know $1 \in \mathbb{Z}/n$.

$\text{Inverses : }$ We know $\gcd(a,n)=1$ for any $a \in \mathbb{Z}/n$. This comes from the definition of $\mathbb{Z}/n$. Then $1=ax+ny \implies n(-y)=ax-1 \implies ax\equiv1 \pmod{n}$. Because $n$ prime we know either $x \in \mathbb{Z}/n$ or $x \equiv k \pmod {n}$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}/n$. Then there exists an inverse for $\cdot$ in $\mathbb{Z}/n$ .

The point I'm struggling with are showing there's a neutral element and an inverse to the sum. The only neutral element I can think of for $a \in \mathbb{Z}/n$ is $kn$, since $a +kn \equiv a$. But $kn \equiv 0\pmod{n}$ and then $kn \notin \mathbb{Z}/n$. How could I proceed?

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/610383/11619) answer all your questions? This is close to being a FAQ.

Comment: $\Bbb Z/n$ should include $0$.

Comment: And you have $\gcd(a,n)=1$ for all $\overline{a}\in\Bbb{Z}/n, \overline{a}\neq\overline{0}$ if and only if $n$ is a prime.