# Is this proof by contradiction correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, solution-verification

In proving that $\mathbb{Z}/n$ is a field iff $n$ is prime, I found the following proof by contradiction of the $\Rightarrow$ implication and was wondering if it is correct.

---

Assume $\mathbb{Z}/n$ is a field. We know $(\mathbb{Z}/n, +, \cdot)$ is a conmutative ring and therefore the assumption is nothing else than the assumption that there is a multiplicative inverse in $\mathbb{Z}/n$. This means

$$
\forall a \in \mathbb{Z}/n, \exists x \in \mathbb{Z}/n \space|\space a \cdot x \equiv1 \pmod{n}
$$

Assume $n$ is not prime; this is, $n=rq$ for $r, q <n$. Then $r, q \in \mathbb{Z}/n$. Our assumption tells us there are $x, x' \in \mathbb{Z}/n$ such that $xr \equiv1 \pmod{n}, x'q \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$. However, this implies

$$xr \cdot x'q \equiv 1 \iff x\cdot x \cdot n \equiv 1 \pmod{n} $$

which is absurd: any multiple of $n$ is congruent to $0$ modulo $n$. The contradiction arouse from assuming $n$ is not prime. Then if $\mathbb{Z}/n$ is a field, $n$ must be prime.

---

Is this proof correct?

Comment: It looks Correct to me !

Comment: Thank you @Prem! Very new to algebra so I certainly appreciate the validation.

Comment: Please don't repost your [prior-closed dupe question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4592567/242). For a `solution-verification` question to be on topic you must specify precisely which step in the proof you question, and why so. This site is not meant to be an open-ended proof checking machine.

Comment: Apart from the typo in $x\cdot x\cdot n\equiv 1\mod n$ and the missing additional remark that $r,q\ne 0$ (ensuring that $r$ and $q$ have a multiplicative inverse) , the proof is valid.

Comment: Your first displayed equation is false; even if $\mathbb{Z}/n$ is a field, the statement $\forall a\in \mathbb{Z}/n\exists x\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mid ax\equiv 1\pmod{n}$ is **false**: because the class of $0$ does not have a multiplicative inverse. Any contradiction you found is tainted by writing down a statement that is always false. The correct statement must exclude $a=0$.